# How to split up an extra large class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have half a dozen IO related classes, all with their little utility classes etc, all weighing in at ~1000 lines. They all have to be in one class together because the root class is templated to define address space and usage mode which makes it very convenient to use its members outside.

Its become a pain to work on it though, since it takes so much scrolling and clicking and I have to remember where everything is. Afaik there is no such thing as a partial class in c++, is there any other way to split up this huge header file?

Comment: Would it alleviate your problem to use `friend` classes?  You could split out code into as many `friend` classes as you need, and these classes would still have access to the internals of the main class.  And even though you would be using multiple classes, it would sort of act like a single "conceptual" class.

Comment: Since it ain't obvious how to split it, it ain't gone be obvious how to use it. Get a bigger screen;)

Comment: In visual studio 2013 you can collapse code section. Collapse everything and only open what you are working on.

Comment: Honestly, @Ben has the best, and easiest solution without having to restructure your code.

Answer (score 4):

You can declare the class in a header file and then separate each of the definitions into its own cpp file.  Then you have one master cpp file that includes all of those sub-cpp files. When compiling, you just reference the "master" file as the input file.

Many templated classes are created this way. They use a `.tcc` extension to mark the implementation of certain functions so it is not in the header file itself. C++ does not care where the functionality is implemented, so long as it can be found at compile and linking time. So, though C++ doesn't have `partial classes` per se, the functionality of a `partial class` is still implicitly available.

For example,

```
//BigClass.h
#pragma once
class BigClass
{
    // Lots of methods
    public:
        void doMethodA();
        void doMethodB();
        // ...
};
```

Then, there are a lot of subfiles that implement one method per file.

```
//BigClass_doMethodA.cc
void BigClass::doMethodA()
{
    // Method body
}
```

In another file you do the same thing.

```
//BigClass_doMethodB.cc
void BigClass::doMethodB()
{
    // Method body
}
```

Then, you have one "master" cpp file.

```
//BigClass.cpp
#include "BigClass.h"
#include "BigClass_doMethodA.cc"
#include "BigClass_doMethodB.cc"
```

The preprocessor will glue all of the files together into one big file for compilation, but you will have the benefit of not having to do that yourself.

Comment: Recommend not using "cpp file" when discussing headers. Someone will misinterpret and put the definitions in a cpp file and then have to ask the "Why can't I link?" question. This is probably better described as master header and sub headers

Comment: See the example I am giving.  I do mean "cpp file" in this case, but it is not something I would normally recommend. My solution takes advantage of the C/C++ Preprocessor to create one large cpp file from a bunch of smaller ones. Technically, you could use whatever file extension you want for the smaller files to help you distinguish the difference and even include the `#error` directive in between `#ifdef` and `#endif` directives to make sure the sub-files are never included directly.

Comment: If you ever look at the STL classes, you will see that this is the same principle they use.

Comment: Yes, but they do not use cpp files. They are header files with a different name so that they can be easily identified as template implementation files. They are not their own separate entities that compile to object code as the common usage of the term cpp file suggests. There is nothing wrong the idea you intend, but poorly chosen terminology warps your answer so that it can be read as suggesting something that will not work.

Answer (score 1):

If it does not make sense to split the code up because of templating and inheritance reasons, then it makes no sense to physically split the code up. It *should* all be in the same file. IDE's usually have good ways of dealing with gratuitis code. For VS2013, you can use the collapse code feature. If you start out with this:

[image]

You can collapse things that you dont need to work on and expand things that you want to see:

[image]

This will make code editing easier.

Do this by either:

1. Collapsing things you dont want to see manually and keeping things you do want. This can be done via the little +/- on the edge of the code sections.
2. Use *View->Outlining->Colapse to Definition* to get single definitions and then use the + to open what you are working on.

There are also other useful code simplifying tools in the *View->Outlining* menu.

Comment: "It should all be in the same file." - this is a very strange thing to hear. Usually people advocate for splitting up things to a ridiculous degree, to the point where you can't figure out which file/class/function to find things in.

Comment: I look at it the same way I do writing a paragraph. A sentence is a thought. A paragraph is a set of related thoughts supporting an idea. When the idea changes, the paragraph changes. Sometimes you get really long paragraphs. The worry about long paragraphs (and files) is in what it typically represents: A poorly thought-out, sprawling mish-mash. That is what needs to be avoided. Chopping stuff up willy-nilly to meet a maximum size requirement is going to result in less readability and possibly a more brittle design.

Comment: @immibis Might be the way to go if that helps. But i find things related to class A, should all be in A.cpp. I could put them in A_input.cpp and A_output.cpp if that helped, and maybe that would be worth it. But i Want to be able to look at A.h find my function declaration, then switch to A.cpp and find the function definitions there. This is doubly true for Templates, it should all be in the `h` file not sprawled across multiple.

Comment: @Ben I'm not saying it's wrong, just that people usually say the opposite (and *those* people are wrong)